# Supporting WebSockets on Phusion Passenger with em-websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, passenger, eventmachine, em-websocket

I am trying to support a WebSocket interface to my Rails application. I am on Rails 4 with no plans of moving to Rails 5 immediately. I use Phusion Passenger 5.0.30 behind nginx.

I want to use em-websocket (+eventmachine) to build this support. What are Passenger configuration settings that I must use?

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name ergo;
  root /home/user/www/testapp/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;

  passenger_max_preloader_idle_time 0;

  location /notify {
    proxy_pass http://ergo:3004/notify;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }
}
```

Using the above configuration, and the following code for start the EM loop in `config/initializers/event_machine_init.rb`, I cannot get the websocket server to work. Are there additional config changes needed?

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-websocket'

module EventMachineInit
  def self.start
    if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
      PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
      # for passenger, we need to avoid orphaned threads
        if forked && EM.reactor_running?
          EM.stop
        end

        Thread.new do
          puts "Starting EventMachine thread"
          EM.run do
            EM::WebSocket.run(host: "0.0.0.0", port: 3004) do |ws|
              ws.onopen do |handshake|
                puts "WebSocket connection open"
                ws.send "Hello Client, you connected to #{handshake.path}"
              end

              ws.onclose { puts "WebSocket connection closed" }

              ws.onmessage do |msg|
                puts "Received message: #{msg}"
                ws.send "Pong: #{msg}"
              end
            end
          end
        end
        die_gracefully_on_signal
      end
    end
  end

  def self.die_gracefully_on_signal
    Signal.trap("INT")  { EM.stop }
    Signal.trap("TERM") { EM.stop }
  end
end
```

EDIT: I was able to get the above to work with changes suggested by @Priyank Gupta in the comments under the question. The changes were:

```
proxy_pass http://ergo:3004/notify;
```

became:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3004/notify;
```

I also added:

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

Comment: Are your nginx and application log seeing request hits ? What protocol are you using for websockets ?

Comment: Nginx log is seeing hits. I didn't get what you mean by which protocol. Isn't WebSockets the protocol.

Comment: yeah. Try changing `proxy_pass http://localhost:3004/notify;` and adding `proxy_redirect off;` in nginx config.